# How to edit gnus groups parameters by hand

Tags: emacs, gnus

An extension I have puts an option in my `*Gnus Customize*` buffer, but whenever I set it for any given group, I can no longer successfully open `*Gnus Customize*`. Therefore, I can't unset it (because the buffer errors out whenever I try to open it with <kbd>G c</kbd>). Where do the `group parameters` get saved so that I can go fix it by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was either `~/.newsrc` or `~/.newsrc.eld`. I got rid of them both and things seem to be back to normal.